# Is the following figure DAG?

Tags: data-structures, graph, directed-acyclic-graphs

I have been through multiple definitions of DAG and all of them say that it is a directed graph without cycles. Also, it is said that it has topological ordering.

Now the following figure is directed graph and does not have cycles.

[image: Directed graph with no cycles edges are (0,1),(0,2),(2,1)]

But looking at the ordering of edges (look at edge (2,1)), it is not topologically ordered.

Is this still a DAG or every edge must be topologically ordered for this graph to be a DAG??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes this is a DAG. To check: you cannot go from one node and reach it again following the edges in the graph. As a matter of fact, the graph is *complete* directed acyclic graph in a sense that it holds the maximum number of possible edges in a DAG of 3 nodes. Adding any new edge would turn it into a cyclic digraph.

For complete DAGs, there is only one topological order. In your case it is 0>2>1.

An informal way to generate a topological ordering:

1. pick the source -- the one with zero incoming edges (in case there
   are many, choose anyone).
2. Remove it from the graph (with its outgoing edges of course).
3. Repeat until you end up with empty graph.

Comment: Ok. Pretty convinced with your explanation.....but the thing is that according to topological ordering for any edge (u,v) => u < v. Now for edge (2,1) but 2 > 1. I got ur point that it is a DAG but what about 2 being greater than 1. Please help me out.

Comment: > or < is a just relation (not greater or smaller). So (u,v) mean u appears before v in the ordering relation (whether you name it < or >)

Comment: Thanks, convinced again. Someone down voted the question dont know why. I asked the same question on CS stack exchange and got reputation. Sometimes people are unfair.